# cv2.imshow() argument format?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am modifying the pixels of an image I read via a camera and I am trying to see it on the screen using `imshow()`, but I end up getting a black screen each time.
The only way it works is if I save it first(using `imwrite()` and then read it again (using `imread()`)

This yields a black screen:-

```
def foo(im):
    cv2.show(im)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

ret_im = some_fn(some_image)
foo(ret_im)
```

Whereas, this gives the correct image:-

```
def foo(im):
    cv2.show(im)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

ret_im = some_fn(some_image)
cv2.write("some_name.png",ret_im)
ret_im = cv2.read("some_name.png")
foo(ret_im)
```

The original image also works like a charm. Eg:

```
def foo(im):
    cv2.show(im)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

foo(some_image)
```

I think, this has something to do with the input data format. I have tried matching it with the `some_image` type, by modifying the image.

I must mention here that I am modifying the image treating it as a list and at the end, converting it to numpy array using: `numpy.array(list_name)`

So, it can be considered as working with :

```
def foo(im):
    cv2.show(im)
    cv2.waitKey(10)

ret_im = numpy.array(some_fn(some_image))
foo(ret_im)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image format required "uint8" numbers.
I was using int32 numbers which was causing the issue.